# sidekiq returns Net::SMTPSyntaxError: 501

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp, sidekiq

I am using rails and sidekiq for sending out mails through background, however when i trigger emails it returns

> error_message"=>"501 5.0.0 HELO requires domain address\n",
>   "error_class"=>"Net::SMTPSyntaxError",
>   "failed_at"=>1453973913.4580712, "retry_count"=>3,

although it works fine when i shoot mails directly without sending it to sidekiq, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found it, was because my smtp authentication was wrong.

But i got the require domain address error initially fixed by adding

> O AllowBogusHELO=bool

in sendmail configuration, but again got an error 'smtp authentication failed' whence i have got the clue.